# LiveData with condition

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I want to use livedata in an recyclerview. But I only want to observe Livedata with a certain ID. The data gets loaded, but it doesn't update.
So here is the function in m Dao:

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM zutaten_table NATURAL JOIN table_ref WHERE table_ref.rezeptid = :id")
    fun getZutatenforRezept(id:Int):  LiveData<List<ZutatenData>>
```

I use a Viewmodel and a repository like this:

```
class LiveDataZutatenRepository(private  val rezeptDao: AllDao, rezeptID: Int){
    val Dao = rezeptDao
    val allZutaten =  Dao.getZutatenforRezept(rezeptID)

}

class SpecialZutatViewmodel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application){
    private val repository: JustGetSpecialTypesRepository
    private lateinit var repositoryLiveData: LiveDataZutatenRepository
    lateinit var ZutatenforRezept : LiveData<List<ZutatenData>>
    val Dao : AllDao
    init {
        Dao = EssenRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).allDao()
        repository = JustGetSpecialTypesRepository(Dao)
    }

    suspend fun getRezeptWithZutat(id: Int):RezeptWithZutat{
        return repository.getRezeptWithZutatFromID(id)
    }
    suspend fun getMengen(rezid: Int): List<RefZutatRezept>{
        return repository.getMengen(rezid)
    }

     fun setLiveData(rezeptid: Int){
        repositoryLiveData = LiveDataZutatenRepository(Dao, rezeptid )
        ZutatenforRezept = repositoryLiveData.allZutaten
    }


 }
```

an in my view I use an observer to get the livedata:

```
        val zutatViewmodel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SpecialZutatViewmodel::class.java)
         lifecycleScope.launch {
             zutatViewmodel.setLiveData(rezeptid)
         }
        zutatViewmodel.ZutatenforRezept.observe(this, Observer { zutaten ->
            zutaten?.let { adapterzut.setZutaten(it) }
        })
```

Viewholder function:

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ZutatenViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = zutaten[position]
        holder.rezepteItemView.text = current.zutname
        if(current.bild>=0) {
            holder.rezeptePicView.setImageResource(current.bild)
            holder.rezeptePicView.drawable.isFilterBitmap = false
        }
    }
```

unfortenatly the list doesn't update when the database is changed, but is loaded correctly the first time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please write your "onBindViewHolder()" method.

Comment: `    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ZutatenViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = zutaten[position]
        holder.rezepteItemView.text = current.zutname
        if(current.bild>=0) {
            holder.rezeptePicView.setImageResource(current.bild)
            holder.rezeptePicView.drawable.isFilterBitmap = false
        }
    }
`

Comment: Who is calling "observe()" methods you provided? you wrote "in my view" but WHO is this view? Please try to include useful code....we cannot ask you important code each time.......

Comment: add else to your if condition must be update

Answer (score 1):

it seems you are using room. So, instead of passing the entire list to the adapter, you can pass a list of all the ids in the database. Then, in the onBindViewholder, you can call the rest of the elements by using the id of the element. the code sample below might give you a better idea -

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PassViewHolder, position: Int) {
    viewModel.getById(getItem(position)).asLiveData().observe(lifecycleOwner) {
        try {
            holder.bind(it)
        }catch (e:Exception){
            Log.e(TAG,"PassData passed = null")
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

I had the same problem where the views weren't getting updated but the changes where still being recorded. this method fixed it all.

the below piece of code returns the elements linked to the id as a flow.

```
viewModel.getById(getItem(position))
```

And then you covert it to live data and add an observer.

---

if you want, you can have a look at the [project](https://github.com/Vaishnav-Kanhirathingal/Save-Pass/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/kenetic/savepass/adapters/PassAdapter.kt) where I implemented this